# Can we sign Powershell commands instead of signing scripts?

Tags: windows, powershell, networking

I have came to scenario where I need to sign command and execute it on target system using `Invoke-Command` in `Script-Block { }` option.

How can we sign Powershell command and execute it on target system?

Comment: You could make a script that does nothing else and then sign the script. Is there a particular reason you don't want to use a script?

Comment: I am directly execute commands in script block and don't want to increase IO operations using script file.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot sign commands. You can only sign scripts.

The good news is that the script signing requirement only applies to scripts. Commands inside a Invoke-Command script block do not need to be signed.

I am not sure what problem you are tying to solve. If you have some obscure internal requirement, then you could sign the initiating script that calls the invoke command.